# What part of the sentence is this called

Tags: syntax

Can you explain whether the following that I'm going to write in the body section is considered the subject or not? If not, what is it considered?

My favourite place

Comment: "My favourite place" is a noun phrase. Whether it's a subject or not depends on context.

Answer (score 1):

FumbleFingers is right.  In this sentence the phrase is the subject:

`My favourite place, Montpellier, was in the news today.`

In this sentence it is the object:

`I often return to my favourite place, Montpellier.`